# Segmentation fault (core dumped) when using NGINX Reverse proxy. Flask

Tags: python, nginx, flask

I am using this flask profiler

https://github.com/muatik/flask-profiler

Locally it works fine with a simple flask app, however, when I run on it on my server that uses NGINX as a reverse proxy it will work for a few minutes and then return

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I am using the default config

```
    # You need to declare necessary configuration to initialize
# flask-profiler as follows:
app.config["flask_profiler"] = {
    "enabled": app.config["DEBUG"],
    "storage": {
        "engine": "sqlite"
    },
    "basicAuth":{
        "enabled": True,
        "username": "admin",
        "password": "admin"
    },
    "ignore": [
        "^/static/.*"
    ]
}
```

I'm 90% sure this is being caused by the reverse proxy as that is the only thing that has changed. I found this https://github.com/muatik/flask-profiler/issues/65 but have not had any luck even after setting the correct path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issues by adding the following to my NGINX rules

```
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
```